# Android - Switch between layouts

Tags: android

I have two layouts, what is the best way to switch between the two layouts when a user clicks on a button?

Comment: Refer for Switch between [Layouts](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities/)

Answer (score 6):

You could call `setContentView(R.layout.layout2)` on ButtonClick

Comment: This isn't working for me. I mean, the button that switches to layout2 from activity_main is working, but the button that switched back to activity_main from there is completely unresponsive. I made sure to inflate layout2, which did stop the app from crashing, but it didn't actually let the button do anything. :/

Comment: I used the same thing but now when i switch layout, there is no margin at bottom or top. The layout goes behind bottom navbar of android

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use [android.widget.ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html). With it you can create different layout from xml and then switch among them with simple method like this:

```
   ViewFlipper viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.myViewFlipper);

   // you can switch between next and previous layout and display it
   viewFlipper.showNext();
   viewFlipper.showPrevious();

  // or you can switch selecting the layout that you want to display
  viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
  viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(viewFlipper.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.secondLayout)
```

Xml example with tree layouts:

```
     <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/myViewFlipper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
               [...]
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
               [...]
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/thirdLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
              [...]
            </LinearLayout>
      </ViewFlipper>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ViewSwitcher.

1. make one layout file that includes two layouts. your two layouts should be place in viewswitcher.
2. associate an onclick listener that switch two layout with a button.

if you separate two layouts in different file, you can use  tag in layout xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Use "fragment manager" after creating fragments and putting your layouts into it on run time or "view pager" as it can also add swapping effect. Do not use setContentView(R.layout.your_layout) without clearing the previous layout (use "gone" or "clear") for changing layout on run time as it slows down your app (because now there are two layout running) and even creates confusion for the app.